# Can we add Change Password functionality after login into Shopify online store?

Tags: laravel, shopify

Shopify does not provide change password functionality in online store. Can we implement it using Laravel?

I want to add change password functionality for customers in shopify online store after login into store using Laravel.

Comment: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/your-account/logging-in/reset-password

Comment: You talking about the frontend customer or backend admin user, please clear first?

Comment: Quick question, How would Laravel benefit in this? I would not suggest using a separate application just to reset a password? I would suggest to do some more research on what is needed to get this functionality.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.